# Send BACKSPACE keystroke in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have made some code in Word VBA and at the end I need 1 backspace keytroke. How is this achievable?

Comment: Thank you, this might work. Is there a way to easily place the inssertion point on the starting point of current page (top left) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple way to send a backspace (but not the most robust solution) :

```
SendKeys ("{BACKSPACE}")
```

A safer way to do this :

```
Selection.MoveLeft Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Delete
```

If something is already selected, and you want to delete just the last character, preface the above by :

```
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
```

To go to the start of the current page :

```
ActiveDocument.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToRelative, 0).Select
```

Answer (score 13):

The simplest solution is just:

```
Selection.TypeBackspace
```

Comment: For some conditions, this method is not working as our expectation. ie : in numbering if we do this method when cursor right next of the numbering, instead of "reformat" the numbering, this method will delete the numbering including the newline character.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way if your text is in a string or text field:

```
dim strText as string
strText = yourdatasourcehere
strText = left(strText,len(strText) - 1)
youroutputsource = strText
```

This works for spaces too as they are counted with the len

Answer (score 0):

Backspace is character code (8). The sendkeys equivalent is {BACKSPACE}.