# How to backspace in c# word interop?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

How to insert backspace in c# word interop? I tried using `myRange.InsertBefore("\b\b");`
But does not do anything.

I also tried `myRange.Delete(Type.Missing);` but deletes all the contents of the range.

I got myRange through thw following:

```
object start = 0, end = 0;
Word.Range myRange = doc.Range(ref start, end);
if(myRange.Find.Execute("wordtofind"))
{
    //some codes here
}
```

All I want is to backspace before the first character on the range.

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605653/send-backspace-keystroke-in-word-vba  :-)

Answer (score 4):

What about [`TypeBackspace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.typebackspace.aspx)?

```
Range myRange = oWordDoc.Range(ref start, end);
myRange.Select();

app.Selection.GoTo(1, 1);
app.Selection.TypeBackspace();
```